# eloquent relation shows null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have migrations for Users and Projects like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->bigInteger('last_used_society_id');
            $table->bigInteger('last_used_project_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('eplan_name')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('society_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            //$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });

        Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('society_id')->references('id')->on('societies');
        });
```

table Users is altered after to add foreigns:

```
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('last_used_society_id')->references('id')->on('societies');
        $table->foreign('last_used_project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
    });
```

and in model of User i have this:

```
public function ActualProject(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project', 'users_last_used_project_id_foreign');
}

public function ActualSociety(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Society', 'users_last_used_society_id_foreign');
}
```

but when i try to call `$user->ActualProject` it return `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why using 'users_last_used_project_id_foreign'?

just use the column's name as it is ...

```
public function ActualProject(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project', 'last_used_project_id');
}
```

Comment: nice. thank you didnt know i can use column name... what i found on net was using foreign key

Comment: @Petr, if your foreign id was `project_id` then you dont need to define it in your relationship. Laravel will catct it. You modify, so you need to tell laravel your primary key name.